# Android ListView.setAdapter() nullpointer exception

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm getting a nullptr, I read a few posts but I can't seem to hunt this one down, I'm new to app development; any help would be greatly appreciated. The error is occurring here:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.ciltkick.nom.MainActivity";

    private EditText editTxt;
    private Button btn;
    private ListView list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNom);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/msg"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addNom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            android:onClick="addNom"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ciltkick.nom" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"></uses-sdk>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondaryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_secondary"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.ciltkick.nom.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
01-07 17:52:04.494  26339-26339/com.example.ciltkick.nom E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-07 17:52:06.455  26339-26339/com.example.ciltkick.nom E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ciltkick.nom/com.example.ciltkick.nom.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.ciltkick.nom.MainActivity
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.ciltkick.nom.MainActivity
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check your source code. Do you actually have a class in the package `com.example.ciltkick.nom` called `MainActivity`? If so, maybe your classes are not being put in the APK. You can check this by using `aapt dump` tool or one of a number of APK analysis tools.

Comment: @user370305 This isn't a problem of the code. The Manifest would certainly be useful, but as I said in my comment above, I think it is probably a packaging problem.

Comment: @KristyWelsh OP isn't instantiating `MainActivity`. Android is trying to do it. Obiviously `MainActivity` is in the manifest and marked as the root Activity (ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER). OP is just trying to launch his app.

Comment: Get rid of your meta-data tag for SecondActivity in the Manifest and I bet it runs.

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Comment: @DavidWasser I think you're on the right track, I've been searching in the direction of packaging issues but since I don't really know what I'm doing I'm probably overlooking something basic

Comment: @sqlbuddy - Have you enabled Android Private Libraries in Build path? Like , `Java Build Path ->
Order and Export ->
Android Private Libraries`. Just need to be sure about `Android Support Library v7` for `ActionBar`

Comment: Just get a list of the classes in your APK using an appropriate tool. See if you actually have a class called "com.example.ciltkick.nom.MainActivity" in the APK. If not, this should set you on the right track to figure it out.

Comment: @DavidWasser From what I gather, the content of manifest-merger-debug-report.txt should be the same as what's in .apk; can't seem to get apktool to cooperate after installing... anyway manifest-merger-debug-report.txt contains the following:                           application
ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:5:5
MERGED from com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3:16:5
MERGED from com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3:16:5
 android:label [...stuff here which won't fit...] 
activity#com.example.ciltkick.nom.MainActivity

Comment: @user370305 I have import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 in the header of MainActivity.java

Comment: @sqlbuddy - Yes, but we have to check it weather it also build in apk source code

Comment: @user370305 in manifest-merger-debug-report.txt we have in the manifest section: ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:4:5
MERGED from com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3:15:5
MERGED from com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3:15:5 and in the application section: ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:5:5
MERGED from com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3:16:5
MERGED from com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3:16:5 Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: ... I really wish I could format these comments so they are easier on the eyes @user370305

Comment: Instead of trying to format comments, you can just edit your original post and add this data. In any case, the MANIFEST isn't the problem. You need to see if your **class is in the APK with the correct package name!** You've just posted stuff from the manifest!

Comment: please post the "package" line of your `MainActivity` source code. It should be like the first or second line in your source code.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68400/discussion-on-question-by-sqlbuddy-android-listview-setadapter-nullpointer-exc).